# ANTLR : AST, Java

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to generate `AST` after parsing a HTML file.

```
grammar XHTML2CSV;

options {
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    CELLULE;
    LIGNE;
    CELLULEG    =  '<td>';                                              
    CELLULED    =  '</td>';
    DEBUTCOL    =  '<tr>';
    FINCOL      =  '</tr>';
    DTAB        =  '<table';
    STAB        =  ' align=\"center\"';
    FTAB        =  ' border=\"1\">';
    FINTAB      ='</table>';                                


ligne 
    : DEBUTCOL cellule+ FINCOL -> ^(LIGNE cellule);

cellule : CELLULEG CHAINE CELLULED            
        -> ^(CELLULE CHAINE);
```

And when I parse somthing like :

```
  <tr>
    <td>"Cellule 1"</td>
    <td>"Cellule 2"</td>
    <td>"Cellule 3"</td>
  </tr>
```

I just get the tree : nil ---> LIGNE ---> CELLULE ---> "Cellule 1"
How can I do to get all the children of LIGNE in the AST ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you should be using ALTLR with HTML.

Comment: Using ANTLR is too complex for such a simple task, and XML/XHTML has a complex grammar, some facets of which you haven't accounted for with your simple grammar (i.e. URL-escaped stuff). Stick to SAX.

Comment: If the goal is to parse real HTML, OP will need all the power of ANTLR to handle all the complexities.  HTML as used by browsers is a mess, and it comes in several flavors of mess.

Comment: @Chris, you seem to contradict yourself (_"ANTLR is too complex"_ and _"XML/XHTML has a complex grammar"_). Anyway, yes, you raise a valid point of using existing tools for this, but one can definitely use ANTLR to parse (X)HTML.

Comment: I'm not contradicting myself. ANTLR is complex to do the grammar in, and XHTML has a complex grammar. Don't encourage a bad solution, and advise to a proper solution.

Comment: @Chris, okay, then I simply didn't understand what you meant (I still don't...). Note that your remarks "ANTLR is complex" and "XHTML has a complex grammar" are highly debatable and don't exclude the fact that ANTLR can be used to parse (X)HTML. I suspect you know little about ANTLR, in which case your opinion isn't really worth much, IMO. Sure ANTLR has a learning curve that is a bit steep perhaps, but once you're used to working with it, it isn't all that complex.

Comment: It's just not applicable for this kind of situation. I'm sure most people here agree. It's like using a pneumatic drill when a hammer will do.

Comment: Neither of use know if that's true. You (nor I) don't know what the OP's exactly trying to do. Simply stating that ANTLR is too complex and XHTML's grammar is too complex is plain silly (all IMO, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot a `+` in your rewrite rule:

```
ligne 
  :  DEBUTCOL cellule+ FINCOL -> ^(LIGNE cellule+)
  ;                                       //    ^
                                          //    |
                                          //    +--- ici!
```

FYI: there's an HTML grammar on the ANTLR website: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/HTML

Comment: Thx Bart :) Didn't know that I could use regexp inside.